# Hive Data Type : Double Precision & Scale

Tags: hadoop, hive, double, double-precision

I am using CDH 5.3.0 and Hive 0.12. I am having a Hive table with columns defined as double.

I am loading data to these double columns with 2 scale of precision after decimal point from a HDFS sequence file. For example, in my HDFS sequence file my data is like - 100.23 or 345.00. I need to choose double as my data value can be a big value like "3457894545.00"

My requirement is to display two scale precision after decimal point while querying to the Hive table. So with the example data, mentioned above, if i query for this column then I would need to see the value as "100.23" or "345.00".

But with Hive 0.12, I am getting only single precision after decimal point, i.e. value is getting truncated to "100.2" or "345.0".

I tried with "decimal" data type giving syntax as "decimal(3,2)" but in that case my value is getting completely rounded off i.e. "100" or "345".

I was goggling to see if there is any option to define custom precision to a double data type and found that custom precision can be given from hive 0.13 on wards.

Is Hive 0.12 double data type shows only single precision after decimal point. Do i need to apply any custom fix. Kindly suggests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't you googled before posting this question?

Comment: If the decimal(5,2) , then what would be output displayed for value such as 3457894545.85

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare as `decimal(5,2)`.

The syntax is `DECIMAL(precision, scale)`. Precision means the number of digits of this number including the digits after the dot.